# Is this conditional statement true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

If $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$, then $A\subseteq C$ and $B\subseteq D$.
Is this statement false if, say, $A = \{\}, B =\{1\}, C = \{1,2\}$ and $D = \{3,4\}$? Since $A \times B$ will be $\{\}$, which is a subset of $C \times D$, but $B$ is not a subset of $D$.

Comment: It looks like your example is a counterexample to the If-then statement (first sentence of post). I think it holds if $A,B$ nonempty however.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/406068/11994.

Comment: @MarnixKlooster The question linked in your comment is for the converse of the statement of OP. True it's "related", but it's a different question.

Comment: @coffeemath Correct.  But the _answer_ linked in my comment shows $\;A \times B \subseteq C \times D \;\equiv\; A = \emptyset \lor B = \emptyset \lor (A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq D)\;$.  This shows that the OP's conditional statement is true (and even is an equivalence) if $\;A\;$ and $\;B\;$ are nonempty, as you already observed.

Comment: @MarnixKlooster I agree-- maybe I should have read through the answer to see if it dealt with the reverse direction, which it did as you note. +1 on comment.

Answer (score 1):

You're quite right, we need to assume that $A \neq \emptyset$ and $B \neq \emptyset$ for this to be true.  Otherwise, we can find counterexamples, such as $A=C=D=\emptyset$ and $B \neq \emptyset$.

Now suppose $A \neq \emptyset$ and $B \neq \emptyset$.

If $a \in A$, then, since $B$ is non-empty, there exists $b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in A \times B$.  Since $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$, we find $$(a,b) \in C \times D=\{(c,d):c \in C \text{ and } d \in D\}.$$  Hence $a \in C$.

Similarly we can show $b \in B$ implies $b \in D$, since $A$ is non-empty.